# What is reference impedance in microwave?

Tags: impedance, pcb-antenna

What is reference impedance in microwave circuit design and applications? What should be value of reference impedance in antenna design?

Comment: Explain what a reference impedance is. You probably mean **characteristic impedance**. Most often 50 ohms is used as the characteristic impedance. That does not mean you cannot use anything else. If you want to make a 10 ohms, 60 ohms, 100 ohms or 257 ohms system or antenna, you can. But almost all equipment you can buy (including cables and connectors) will be for 50 ohms. You can convert from one impedance level to another using a matching network.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If characteristic impedance is same as reference impedance, then it answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you may be asking in reference to some means of impedance calculation.  If this is the case, as if you were looking at a Smith Chart, the reference impedance can be anything; the Smith Chart uses normalized impedance.  Commonly, the RF community uses 50 Ohm, but it really can be anything (@FakeMoustache comment).